# PHP replacing break lines but still show new line

Tags: php, html

I have a simple HTML text, each section divided with `<br><br>`.

```
*e.g. Lorem ipsum<br><br>
Another lorem ipsum<br><br>
Third section...*
```

I am sending this text via JSON to an android app, so it is sending it also with `<br>` tags, because they are needed to show the sections correctly separated in the app.

The problem is, the Google text speech is reading also those 
 tags.

I want to get rid of them, but still keep the line breaks there.

I manage that text in PHP and I tried:

```
$txt = preg_replace('<br>', '\r\n', $mytxt);$final = strip_tags($txt);
```

But this removes the line breaks completely, so the final text is in one piece and it also replaces ANY **br** word in the text, even if I asked to replace `<br>`, so that is strange.

So how can I keep the line breaks but get rid of html tags?

Comment: Try `str_replace('<br>', '\r\n', $mytxt);` instead.

Comment: `str_replace('<br>', "\r\n", $mytxt);` use " " for the \r\n because in ' ' the string will not converted to newline.

Comment: well this removes all the break lines and the text is in one piece. But this solution at least doesn't replace br word, only tags, so it is better but still I need to keep the sections

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is wrong. Try this:

```php
/**
* Convert BR tags to nl
*
* @param string The string to convert
* @return string The converted string
*/
function br2nl($string)
{
    return preg_replace('/\<br(\s*)?\/?\>/i', "\n", $string);
}
```

Credits: This code snippet comes from the comments from the php site. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: hm, this already shows a break lines in json without <br> tags, but in the app it expects a HTML text and it ignores \n as it doesn't make any break line there. But maybe I need to reconsider the behavior in the app, thanks for this.

Comment: If you want to remove the line breaks `\n` too, just replace `"\n",` with `"",`. Or just use `strip_tags()`.

Comment: but I need there new lines, but not as visible HTML tags, strip_tags will remove also HTML tags but also new lines. But I will fix it in the app, replacing <br> only for text to speech engine, so it will display the text with <br> but will read the text without it

Answer (score 0):

Strip tags might help you...

```
<?php

    $mytxt = '*e.g. Lorem ipsum<br><br>
    Another lorem ipsum<br><br>
    Third section...*';

    $final = strip_tags($mytxt);
```

If you were to echo this in your browser for example, it would appear that there are no new lines, but if you were to view the source of your page you would see that the newlines are infact still intact.

Further information: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: unfortunately in my case strip_tags just removed all the HTML tags, no newlines are there, so the whole text is in one piece

Comment: Your original question just mentioned <br> tags, thats why I suggested this solution. If there are other tags in question, then yes, this is not the way to go.

Comment: yes, I meant remove <br> tags from the text, but still have the text displayed with break lines. That was my request. But strip_tags keeps no break lines.